# Why is my Enchantress's damage so low?

Tags: diablo-iii

My Enchantress's damage seems very low.

```
Level         23

Magic Two-Handed Mace
36.9  DPS
38-44 Damage
0.9   Attacks per second
+4-8  Fire Damage

Strength      50    Life    1058
Dexterity     32    Armor     56
Intelligence 162    Damage 19.32
Vitality      78
```

Her details state her damage should be increased by 161.50% due to her Intelligence, but it looks like it's been almost halved.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your follower damage is low due to the fact that its intentionally reduced to [15% of the DPS they should be doing](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150755834).

On the plus side, they can be great meat shields since they gain a 2.5x bonus to any stat boost on equipment.

You should be using your follower to boost your performance rather than relying on them for damage.

Comment: By no means do I rely on her in combat, but I now see I need the change my equipment strategy for her.  Thanks!