# Which follower is beneficial to each difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a recommended follower to use for each difficulty level? I completed Normal difficulty just fine with my Wizard class w/ my Templar follower. He seems to be doing alright through Nightmare mode. **Should I stick with him or is one suited better for each difficulty?**

Comment: Followers don't come in flavors for different difficulties.  Try http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When choosing a follower, you shouldn't be concerned with what difficulty you're on, but rather how well of a fit they are with your class.  For a Wizard, the Templar is a good fit, as he tends to hold agro and allow you to stay back from the action and use ranged attacks.  In a similar vein, he's also a good choice for the Demon Hunter.

This choice is obvious for the Wizard and Demon Hunter as you want a melee follower to tank for you.  Followers are, after all, just [meat shields](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74622/1351).  For a Monk or Barbarian, the choice is less obvious, but to me the Scoundrel or Enchantress would be better fits than the Templar.

**EDIT:** Thanks to fbueckert for for pointing out that question and the [excellent answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67615/1351) provided by Tater596.

Comment: I would further add that you should analyze what the follower will do for you.  The damage dealt by the followers is not a huge consideration because the difference between them is very small.  Looking at what they do, do you want a templar to heal for you and taunt enemies off you? Do you want the scoundrel to strengthen your crits and slow enemies?  Do you want the enchantress to spam crowd controls?  They are all good, in different situations.